# Calling google navigation from android code and setting name for the destination

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am calling google navigation from android code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+sobj.store_latitude+","+sobj.store_longitude));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

But the destination is shown as a checkered flag.Is there a way in which i can pass the destination name through the intent and show it when i click the checkered flag.